# Unable to get a correct relative path between two files, only when one path is a file and the other a directory, is this normal expected behavior?

Tags: java, java-7, nio

---

Edit:

I was looking at this ../ differently and was attaching ../ mentally with an idea of a directory path with a directory slash already (so directory name + / + ../) , which would point one directory too far back, but now I see that with directory name + ../ is actually correct in this case.

---

I'm unable to get a correct relative path between two files, only when one path is a file and the other a directory, is this normal expected behavior with [Path.relativize(Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize%28java.nio.file.Path%29)? JavaDocs mention that it works with Path objects, but nothing more specific than that.

Here's my example code (running on Windows), which contains comments on what I expected the output to be:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class PathsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Path pathA = Paths.get("C:\\a\\b\\1.txt");
        System.out.println(pathA);
        Path pathB = Paths.get("C:\\a\\b\\2.txt");
        System.out.println(pathB);
        Path relativePathBetween = pathA.relativize(pathB);
        System.out.println("rel: " + relativePathBetween);
        // Outputs "..\2.txt" (for the last print here)
        // Expected: "2.txt"

        pathA = Paths.get("C:\\a\\b\\1.txt");
        pathA = pathA.getParent(); // Obtaining parent here, so C:\a\b
        System.out.println(pathA);
        pathB = Paths.get("C:\\a\\b\\2.txt");
        System.out.println(pathB);
        relativePathBetween = pathA.relativize(pathB);
        System.out.println("rel: " + relativePathBetween);
        // Outputs: "2.txt"
        // Expected: "2.txt"

        // So why does pathA have to be a directory and not a file?
        // Javadocs don't seem to mention that.
    }
}
```

And here's the entire output from the program:

```
C:\a\b\1.txt
C:\a\b\2.txt
rel: ..\2.txt
C:\a\b
C:\a\b\2.txt
rel: 2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`../` means the parent, so in your first example it corresponds to `"C:\\a\\b\\` and the result you get looks fine.

Why do you expect "2.txt", which you would get for `Path pathB = Paths.get("C:\\a\\b\\1.txt\\2.txt");`?